# How to use cron job to execute python script that sends emails without using MTA?

Tags: cron, postfix

I've defined a cron job which use python script to send mails to office365 users emails from office365 email.

```
15 16 * * * 3 cd /home/path_to_app && /home/path_to_env/flaskvenv/bin/python -m app.cron
```

I get this error:

```
CRON[32239]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I've already tried to install postfix and configure it, but that works only for sending emails from command line for fixed recipients. My python script needs to send emails at a certain time and my users are not always the same. That is defined in my python script.

I don't know if postfix or any other MTAis necessary for my problem?

Just to mention that I am using flask_mail in python to send email.
Using above commands works fine when I execute the script without using cron job.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Does your `flask_mail` have an option to choose an external SMTP server?

Comment: Yes, in my configuration file I've already defined MAIL_SERVER='smtp.office365.com' using valid username and password Python script works fine, but the problem is that cron can't execute script.

Comment: Cron does not know your environment variables. flask_mail is using an environment variable (like $PATH) that cron is not aware of.  When you figure out which variable it is, simply declare the variable in the cronjob.

Comment: Does the command work without being in CRON?  If this is the case, you do not need to worry about MTA but about CRON configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I find syntax error in my crontab. I have one more * in my crontab.

So this works fine:

```
15 16 * * 3 cd /home/path_to_app && /home/path_to_env/flaskvenv/bin/python -m app.cron
```